# Equivariant generalization of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ on $\mathbb{CP}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, equivariant-maps, equivariant-cohomology

The connection of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$ on $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is given by 
\begin{equation}
A=\frac{i}{2}\frac{\overline{z} \, dz-z\,d\overline{z}}{1+|z|^2}
\end{equation}
This follows since the first Chern class is represented by the curvature 
\begin{equation}
\frac{i}{2\pi}idA=\frac{i}{2\pi}\frac{dz\wedge d\overline{z}}{(1+|z|^2)^2}
\end{equation}
which is the positive unit volume form of $\mathbb{CP}^1$.

My question is, what is the connection on an *equivariant* version of $\mathcal{O}(1)$. For example, because of the $U(1)$ isometry of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ which rotates its circle fibers, one can consider the $U(1)$-equivariant version of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ on $\mathbb{CP}^1$. What is its connection? Does it involve equivariant differential forms, etc.?

Comment: You may find the discussion in [these notes](http://users.math.yale.edu/~ml562/m852/eq.pdf) enlightening.

Comment: Your formula for $A$ should not have the $i$ in it. This should be the canonical hermitian connection; hence, the connection form should be pure imaginary. Since the curvature is $U(1)$-*invariant*, I'm not sure how the connection form could end up *equivariant*. But I admit I have not studied such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, "equivariant version of $\mathcal{O}(1)$" sounds a bit confusing to me. What we actually do, we endow $\mathcal{O}(1)$ with [equivariant structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_bundle). $U(1)$ acts as follows. Point of total space is a pair $(x, \xi)$, where $x \in \mathbb{P}^1$ i.e. $x$ is line in $\mathbb{C}^2$. $\xi$ is a linear function on this line $l$. $U(1)$ acts on hole $\mathbb{C}^2$, therefore, it acts on such pairs.

*Remark 1* $PSL_2 (\mathbb{C})$ acts on $\mathbb{P}^1$. But one can not endow $\mathcal{O}(1)$ with $PSL_2 (\mathbb{C})$ equivariant structure (it is not entirely obvious). What is obvious, that $PSL_2$ does not act on $\mathbb{C}^2$, then one can not do it as I did for $U(1)$ action.

*Remark 2* Equivariant structure is not unique. You can twist the action of $U(1)$ by a character. More precisely, $U(1)$ acts tautologically on the fibers of hermitian line bundle (denote this action by $\rho (u)$). If you have an equivariant structure on line bundle, you may consider composition of original action and $\rho (u)$. This composition is a new action (i.e. gives new equivariant structure).

An equivariant connection is just a connection (in usual sense), satisfying some extra property. Namely, $\nabla$ commutes with the group action (you know, group acts on sections of equivariant bundle). It is easy to check, that your connection satisfies this condition (nevertheless, Ted Shifrin is right, you should not right $i$ in that formula.).

The correct question would be what is the "equivariant curvature". I will follow notation of classical paper by [Atiyah Bott](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938384900211) (paragraph 8). I may consider coordinates $x_0$, $x_1$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$, $z = \frac{x_1}{x_0}$. 
$x_0$ is a section of $\mathcal{O}(1)$, which trivializes the bundle, restricted to the chart $z \neq \infty$. Consider $U(1)$ action $e^{i \phi} (x_0, x_1) = (x_0 , e^{i \phi} x_1)$. Then group acts trivially on section $s=x_0$ (i.e. $L(s)=0$). Denote by $X$ vector field, which generates $U(1)$ action on $\mathbb{P}^1$
$$X = i z \partial_z- i \bar{z} \partial_{\bar{z}}$$
$$\theta = \frac{\bar{z}dz - z d \bar{z}}{2(1+|z|^2)}$$

$$\iota_X \theta = i \frac{|z|^2}{1+|z|^2}$$

Now we use formula $(8.8)$ from the paper and get

$$c_1 = \frac{i}{2\pi} \Big( -\frac{dz\wedge d\overline{z}}{(1+|z|^2)^2}+ i \frac{|z|^2}{1+|z|^2} u \Big)$$

You can check that this form is equivariantly closed. I.e. it is killed by equivariant differential $d + u \ \iota_X$

Comment: I realize, that I do not give enough details. But if I would, then my post became a survey on equivariant Chern-Weil theory. So, if you have some precise questions, please ask.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, I will read it carefully and get back to you.

Comment: I am a little confused, in the notes recommended by Mike Miller, on page 14, they actually do define an equivariant connection?

Comment: The problem is that Libine and Atiyah-Bott use different approaches and different terminologies. "Equivariant connection for Atiyah-Bott" = "invariant connection for Libine".

Comment: I hope you don't mind enlightening me although it's been a while, why is it $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$ does not act on $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: I do not mind at all, it is an important remark! By the way, you wrote in this remark 1 “it is not entirely obvious”. You know that $PSL_2$ has only trivial two dimensional representation. Then any global section $s$ must be invariant. So $PSL_2$ must map zero locus of $s$ to itself (so there is a point on $\mathbb{P}^1$, which is fixed by $PSL_2$). Contradiction.

Comment: Do you mean global section of the bundle? Is it a contradiction because the action should be transitive ? Sorry for not being faster.

Comment: I have posted another question on equivariant bundles here, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/236784/moment-map-of-equivariant-line-bundles, I think it will be easy for you to answer, please do take a look at it. Thank you.